# loop through an HTML select element and send contents to AJAX via JSON

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to send the id and text value of all the option tags in an HTML select element to AJAX via JSON.

I have an object server side called "myObject" with 2 properties: objId, and objName. And I need to wrap my data in this object before sending.

I've tried 2 different ways of forming the data, but they are both failing.

I think I may be forming the array incorrectly.

Here are the two ways:

this one throws an "Not Enough Arguments" error

```
    var data = {
        myObect: $("#mySelectBox option").each(function (i) {
            return { objId: i.id, objName: i.text() }
        })
    };
```

This one throws a null exception error from the server...which I guess means I'm sending an empty object?

```
    var data = {
        myObect: $.map($("#mySelectBox option"), function (i) {
            return { objId: i.id, objName: i.text() }
        })
    };
```

Any help?  Thanks!

Comment: You could use `$.serializeArray()`: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = {
    myObect: $("#mySelectBox option").map(function () {
        return {
            objId: this.id,
            objName: $(this).text()
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: This returns a json/javascript error: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ensure your data key, if you copied the examples from your code... it's written `myObect` :)

Then, jQuery loop helpers (`map` and `each`) work against raw DOM Elements, not jQuery elements, so your `i.text()` would probably not work. Wrap it: `$(i).text()`.

As the final point, yep, use `map`, as it returns an array of your callback returns. `each` doesn't modify the jQuery collection.